# Error while loading .gz files in Pig Script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have large number of .gz files in HDFS and I am trying to load them using PigStorage to process the data and I am getting the following exception

> java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:137)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:77)
>   at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:85) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:205)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:169) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:139)
>   at org.apache.pig.builtin.TextLoader.getNext(TextLoader.java:55) at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.nextKeyValue(PigRecordReader.java:194)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:530)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:363) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

This might be the result of some of the files are corrupt.

Is pig having any kind of error handling using which I can skip the files that are corrupt. Following is the sample code I am using:

```
cal  = load '$inputdir/CAL/*/*/*/*/*/*/*.gz' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

Comment: I have had to deal with this issue and the way I got around this problem was to first remove all the files that were corrupted in a pre process and feed the good files to the mapper.Unfortunatley PIG will not skip files that are corrupted so you will have to write a pre process or handle this in java mapper.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with corrupted files.

You can use the `mapred.max.map.failures.percent` setting (or `mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent` but this has nothing to do with your case)  to control the percentage of failures you're ok with ignoring.

The problem is that a single mapper can read multiple gz files so a corrupted file that fails the mapper, make it skip files that are ok as well.